# Rails using includes in scope fails to insert table into select statment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails 4.2
I have the following scopes on Orders in orders.rb

```
  scope :sales, -> {where ("orders.order_ref <>'' and date_of_sale IS NOT NULL ")}      
  scope :with_salesman, -> { includes(:pipe_records).where('pipe_records.pipe_part_id=1 AND pipe_records.owner_id IS NOT NULL') }
```

I'm calling this from my orders controller with

```
    @by_salesman=Order.sales.with_salesman
```

Throws an error
    PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

the sql from the console is

```
 SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE (pipe_records.pipe_part_id=1 AND pipe_records.owner_id IS NOT NULL)):
```

I was using join in the scope and it works fine but it dosnt return the salesman data which I want in the recordset , what am I missing to get rails to insert the "select orders.*,pipe_records.* FROM..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `includes` command will only do a join if you specify a field from the included table in a `where` clause. A SQL string doesn't count though; you would need something more like the following:

```
scope :with_salesman, -> { includes(:pipe_records).where(pipe_records: {pipe_part_id: 1}).where("pipe_records.owner_id IS NOT NULL") }
```

Note that the first where condition causes the join, which allows the second to work. Depending on your Rails version, you may have access to `.not` which allows for:

```
scope :with_salesman, -> { includes(:pipe_records).where(pipe_records: {pipe_part_id: 1}).where.not(pipe_records: {owner_id: nil}) }
```

This is nicer, but only supported in Rails 4 onwards.  Since the question specifies Rails 4.2, you should use the second example.

Comment: Thank you , makes sense that it passes sql strings dumbly and requires the .where to identify a column from the joining table, but thank you especially for the .not